# Python PyAtuoGUI - Click on application to be run as administrator

Tags: python-3.x, runas, pyautogui

I have opened my application in administrator mode `os.startfile('myApp.exe', 'runas')` but I'm unable to click on it through my Python script using `pyautogui.click(x,y)`.

Is there any other way to automate my click/typewrite/press (PyAtuoGUI) on an application which is **runas Admin**?

Comment: If target application is run with elevated privileges, same privileges must apply to any program that sends win32api calls. Run your script as an admin.

Comment: with an elevated privilege command prompt, I'm not able use pyautogui.typewrite() from my python script to execute commands in the command prompt - @ŁukaszRogalski